# Having a VPC peering with 2 different AWS accounts and 2nd AWS account having VPN tunnel

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I have 2 AWS accounts `A and B`. On premises client network `c`. I have a VPN tunnel from B TO C which works fine and A TO B with peering.

Now without connecting directly from A to C. is there any other we can  communicate to A to C with the help exisitng VPN tunnel from B TO C

connections i have

1. B to C- VPN tunnel.
2. A to B- peering.

What i want to achieve is

1. A-B-C

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it really isn't a programming question at all. I would suggest posting this on ServerFault.

Comment: posted this. in server fault.